# WooCommerce Order By Not Working Correctly

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to retrieve products from the API and order by price but I am seeing some strange behavior.
An example result set of product prices in order:

```
$1.00
$10.00
$110.00
$2.00
$200.00
$2.50
```

It seems like its comparing these values as strings rather than floats (or something of the sorts). therefore 110.00 comes before 2.00

---

UPDATE:

Here is the url I am hitting (oauth info removed):

```
http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/products?filter%5Bcategory%5D=all&filter%5Bclass%5D=all&filter%5Blimit%5D=6&filter%5Bmin_price%5D=0&filter%5Border%5D=ASC&filter%5Borderby%5D=meta_value&filter%5Borderby_meta_key%5D=_price&filter%5Bq%5D=&filter%5Btag%5D=all&page=1
```

and parameters in a more readable format:

`filter[category]:         all
filter[class]:            all
filter[limit]:            6
filter[min_price]:        0
filter[order]:            ASC
filter[orderby]:          meta_value
filter[orderby_meta_key]: _price
filter[tag]:              all
page:                     1`

Comment: can you show us what have you done?

Comment: I have updated with more information and code for api integration. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide that would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `meta_value_num` for the `orderBy` filter. This was poorly documented in WooCommerce and I have created an issue with them.